# converting a Python list into a sympy matrix

Tags: python, list, matrix, sympy

I have a list of n entries, that I want to convert into a 1 by n sympy matrix. I feel like this shouldn't be hard, but I'm having the hardest time. 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: please provide example list and example matrix

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
from sympy import *
l = [1, 2, 3]
Matrix(l)
```

[image]

Comment: `Matrix(l).T` will make it a row vector with dimensions `1xn`.